# Scrape trading data from bitcoincharts.com using python and PyQT4

Tags: python, pyqt4, scrape

I'm trying to scrape trading data from http://bitcoincharts.com/charts using the following code:

```
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()

url = 'http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/bitstampUSD#rg2zig1-minztgSzm1g10zm2g25'
r = Render(url)

allSelector = 'a[onClick="load_table();return false;"]' 
allButton   = r.frame.documentElement().findFirst(allSelector)
allButton.evaluateJavaScript("this.onclick()")
html = allButton.webFrame().toHtml()

print html.toUtf8()
```

It simulates a click on the "Load raw data" link on the page. When you click on that link in the browser it shows "loading..." for a few seconds and then the table with the raw data.

The HTML generated by the code doesn't contain the data but the "loading" dialog. To me it seems that the javascript interpreter somehow times out, because the javascript function should either produce the data or a "No data returned." dialog when finished successfully (you can find the javascript in the sites HTML).

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you scraping when bitcoincharts has a [perfectly fine API](http://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/)?

Answer (score 1):

I've replied a question similar as this one: [HTML page vastly different when using a headless webkit implementation using PyQT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214939/html-page-vastly-different-when-using-a-headless-webkit-implementation-using-pyq/23165473#23165473)

When "click" the button, you must wait some time for the ajax data load. Add some code like this:

```
for i in range(200): #wait 2 seconds
    app.processEvents()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now the javascript is executed completely. But unfortunately it prints the 'No data returned.' dialog. Any ideas why this succeeds in a browser but fails in the code above?

Comment: Yes, I've tested some code. I thought this line allButton.evaluateJavaScript("this.onclick()") should be allButton.evaluateJavaScript("this.click()"), but it still can't work. Don't know why, can't give you more help.

Comment: Thanks again. As it seems the code works now, but requesting the data is only possible once per minute. I wasn't aware of that during testing.